# HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localhost, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

I got this error while testing my new website Locally on IIS Express on .NET5

I have checked that i have the required dotnet version , adding the dotnet paths to the system  environment variables  and Restarted the visual studio

Comment: Check your Windows Event logs.

Comment: IIS Express/ASP.NET Core module should have written the actual error in Windows event log. Take a look there please. BTW, .NET 5 went end of life for long, you should use .NET 6 and above now.

Comment: The Error ended when i commented this line  =>  using AsPNetCore; , and yes  i know it's no longer supported but i wanted to try some thing , but do i get to to event logs BLZ